# Athena nested view performance

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have an Athena table called "Table_A" and there of millions are records in it, Partitioned by day.
I have a view called "View_A" which is nothing but

```
select * from Table_A
```

without any filtering conditions.

Now I need another view which will fetch only last 5 days of data. But I don't want this new view to be created on top of "Table_A" directly for some internal reasons.

I want this new view on top of "View_A".

Let's say the new view is named as "View_five_days", here is the summary:

View_five_days is pointing to View_A.

```
    create view view_five_days as select * from view_a where day > currentdate - 5
```

View_A is pointing to Table_A

```
    create view view_a as select * from table_a
```

Assuming I have 100 days of data in the original table Table_A : will Athena do full table scan when I do a:

```
select * from View_five_days
```

Or will it only scan the last 5 days of data?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether `Table_A` is partitioned by date. If yes, then you can define the view with an appropriate where clause and only scan the last five days. Otherwise, it will scan the full date column to figure out which rows satisfy the last-five-days condition.

Comment: Question is not about partitioning. Its about view referring to another view.
Yes. Table_A is partitioned by Date.